# jQuery add attribute to SVG string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

Using jQuery I'm trying to add an ID attribute to the 'path' element of the following text template. The text is loaded with RequireJS and is referenced with a variable name (say mySvg).

The intention, is to have a loop based on the number of buttons required, and give each 'path' element (near bottom of markup) a unique ID, after which the text gets appended to a DOM element.

I'd be massively grateful if anyone can show me how (using jQuery) to add the ID attribute and value when the markup is in it's raw text format (ie before it's been added to the DOM).

Many thanks in advance...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.4, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="141px" height="58px" viewBox="0 0 141 58" enable-background="new 0 0 141 58" xml:space="preserve">
<linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="70" y1="62.5" x2="70" y2="-72.5">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.5667" style="stop-color:#3FA9F5"/>
</linearGradient>
<path class="svg button" fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="20" d="M137.5,43.5c0,6.627-5.373,12-12,12h-111
    c-6.627,0-12-5.373-12-12v-30c0-6.627,5.373-12,12-12h111c6.627,0,12,5.373,12,12V43.5z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JQuery to operate on fragments before they are appended to the DOM like this.

```
var e = $(yoursvg);
e.find("path").attr("id", "abcd");

// and then for example add it later

e.appendTo($('body'));
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/3kaCQ/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. How would I reference the 'path' element? I think your example provided would add an id attribute to the root node, and not the 'path'.

Comment: I fixed the original commenters code to match your request and added a demo.